# Environment variable in Docker

Tags: angularjs, docker, environment-variables

I have an app which is working in 2 containers.
A nodeJS and an nginx -container. 
They are working together. 
In the code of the developer is a `src / app / app.config.js`

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .constant('config', {
      URL: 'http://localhost',
      PORT: '8888',

    });
})();
```

The URL and the PORT are fine in case of the developer. To see the app, after building it locally.
But what are we doing? Well we have a jenkins which is performing the npm-install, gulp build etc. After the build. The right generated folders will be copied by the Dockerfiles (one for nginx and one for nodejs). After that we can start containers with this command:

```
docker run --restart=always -d --name "nodejs" our-nodejs-image:11 
docker run --restart=always -d -p 80:80 --name nginx --link nodejs:nodejs our-nginx-image:11
```

The main problem is the following. The URL and the PORT have to change.
So for example we're running our containers on `ec2-123:80` than we have to change the URL to `ec2-123` and the PORT to `80` (because nginx is working as a reverse proxy for our nodejs).

So in this case we are losing the advantage of docker (running an image on each environment). So we need environment variable which we can describe when we're performing the `docker run` command. And this variables needs to be the input of URL: and PORT:.

So the run command for nginx needs to be something like :

```
docker run -e "URL: ec123" -e "PORT:80" --restart=always -d -p 80:80 --name nginx --link nodejs:nodejs our-nginx-image:11
```

Comment: a `docker inspect` should retrieve this information I guess, the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/

Comment: will it not be possible to just change this in the app.config.js? : URL:  process.env.URL and when he tries to run: -e "URL: ec2-123" ?

Comment: tried it, but doesn't seem to work

Comment: Why do you need URL and PORT in your client app at first place? Do host relative calls with XHR/fetch so you don't need to handle CORS etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reusable docker image for AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38436129/reusable-docker-image-for-angularjs)