# Angular 2 build once, deploy anywhere

Tags: angular, tomcat, docker, deployment

Is it possible to follow the principle of *"build once, deploy anywhere"* for an `angular` 2 application?

I keep finding answers that tell me to just build it seperately for every environment, but that's not what I'm looking for.

We're using `docker` and `tomcat`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's definitely possible, could you provide a bit more info? What do you want to change depending on the environment? Is it to have different config for each environment?

Comment: mainly URLs to the backend API. We have seperate URLs for our acceptance environment, development environment etc.
So yes, a different config for each environment.

Comment: Is your angular app served by tomcat?

Comment: @Krikke93 We build some image + provide environment variables with the docker run command and this env will be the values of our configs using a bash-script in our docker container that will fill in the env vars using sed. Like the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38436129/reusable-docker-image-for-angularjs

Comment: @lorenzvth7, does this work for Angular 2? Because first thing I notice is that the person in question is using AngularJS instead of Angular 2.

Comment: @Melou, Angular 2 builds a war file, which is deployed on our tomcat server.

Comment: @Krikke93 Oh I'm sorry, don't know the real difference. So the 'variables' which can be different for each environment are really inside the .war file? You can optionally create the .war file inside your image when you perform docker run and provide your variables with docker run and use the variables inside the image for the .war build but I doubt if it's a good method.

Comment: @Krikke93 do you have any feedback on my answer below?

Answer (score 2):

I think a common point of all app to load config dynamicaly is to use the angular provider called `APP_INITIALIZER`.

This provider allows to execute some code before bootstrapping angular app. Typically the code to execute is something like `get some config from an endpoint, eg /configuration`. Example [here](http://www.learn-angular.fr/how-to-call-an-asynchronous-service-before-bootstrap/)

You can write the code yourself or you can use this lib (under the hood this uses the `APP_INITIALIZER`): https://github.com/ngx-config/core, more precisely the `ConfigHttpLoader`

In the example below, we use the lib to load */configuration* through an http call. This goes in your *app.module.ts*

```
export function configFactory(http: Http): ConfigLoader {
  return new ConfigHttpLoader(http, '/configuration'); // FILE PATH || API ENDPOINT
}    

@NgModule({
imports: [
ConfigModule.forRoot({
          provide: ConfigLoader,
          useFactory: (configFactory),
          deps: [Http]
        })
]
})
```

Then, the way you provide */configuration* depends on how you serve your app. What I did in a project was :

- frontend app is packaged with all configurations (dev.json, integ.json, prod.json)
- pass to docker an environment variable (dev or integ or prod)
- in the Dockerfile of the docker image, make a symlink to the correct config file, depending on the environment, then start the server (in my case it was nginx) :

`CMD ln -nfs /path/to/config/${ENVIRONMENT}.json /path/to/configuration && nginx -g "daemon off;"`

This way your frontend app always load */configuration*, but depending on the environment, the symlink will point to a different config file.

You could use something like this.